# Converting a delete statement into a where clause, T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have removed rows from a results table after it has been built already. I have decided to try to remove the rows from being inserted into the results table in the first place instead.

To remove the appropriate rows from the results table after the fact I used:

```sql
if @InterchangeAction = 'HCR'
        begin

        --Do not allow claims to be output if they have a prior submission marked 'output'
        --and the interchange 'output submission action' is marked as 'hold'
            delete from #ResultSet
             where exists ( select 1 from ClaimSubmissions CS inner join InterchangeInfo I on CS.InterchangeId = I.InterchangeId
                             where #ResultSet.ClaimId = CS.ClaimId
                             and CS.InterchangeId = @InterchangeID
                              and CS.SubmissionStatus = 'OPT'
                              and CS.OutputDate is not NULL
                          )
        end
```

This works as I want but I am thinking it would be more efficient to stop the rows from being added in the first place.

I'm going to start my check with:

```sql
if @InterchangeAction = 'HCR'
```

and then concatenate on to the existing where clause but I am unsure on how to convert the delete statement into a where clause?

Any pointers on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start for this.

Comment: `insert ... where ( all of the existing conditions ) and not exists ( select 42 from ... );`. To get the `and` to work correctly _all_ of the existing `insert` conditions need to be grouped in one set of parentheses. Since your new `where` clause is stuff you want to delete, that becomes `not exists` to avoid inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, aren't you just looking for this?:

```
INSERT #ResultSet 
  (<Column List>)
SELECT 
  <Column List>
FROM 
  WhatHaveYou AS WHY
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from ClaimSubmissions CS 
                            inner join InterchangeInfo I 
                                on CS.InterchangeId = I.InterchangeId
                             where WHY.ClaimId = CS.ClaimId
                              and CS.InterchangeId = @InterchangeID
                              and CS.SubmissionStatus = 'OPT'
                              and CS.OutputDate is not NULL
                          )
```